# time.sleep() or scheduling script. Which one is better approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduling

I have a small script which I want to run after every 15 minutes. I can achieve it in two ways:

1. By putting whole code in while loop `while True:` and at end `time.sleep(900)`.
2. By Scheduling a job to run the script after every 15 minutes once.

Both will work fine, but I am not sure whether the script keeps the resource busy while sleeping.

Please suggest.... Which one is better approach?

Comment: With the second option, you mean a `cron` job?

Comment: Use the second.

Comment: none are busy waits. If you have some scheduling system use it. Else, `sleep` is all right

Comment: The second one will be better: what if your script all of a sudden blocks, and. Furthermore your first option will wait 15 minutes *between* two runs: so if the script itself takes 5 minutes, it will run every 20 minutes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think he means Scheduling as using Windows Task Scheduler. An regards the original question. The scheduler could be a useful option if the script crashes (bad error handling), as it will star a new instance every watever minutes. (Although you should check if the last run has ended before starting whatever you do)

Comment: Yes, as cron job in Ubuntu @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the scheduling system like `cron` on Linux (don't know about Windows, but I woud expect a similar situation there) is the way to go because of its numerous advantages:

- you can rely on it, it is a robust and mature system
- it starts a fresh process every time, thus saving  resources and protecting the system from a possible memory or file descriptor leak in a long running program
- it mails the output and reports crashes to the owner
- you don't have to put your process to the background

The disadvantages:

- if you need to remember a state between runs, you have to save it to a file

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling is more stable and python scripts is more flexible.

If you are debuging or monitoring a software like browsing web pages or you are always modifing the script, The first way is good. You can kill it easily when necessary.  Intuitively I like this one because 15 mins is short so I guess you won't run it long-term.

If you are making a scedule like "periodic backup" or logging or checking something, the second way is better because you need not to manage it once you set.

Comment: For tasks like periodic backup etc., I guess second one is more preferable.

Comment: @SourabhSaini  Yes, "a slip of the tongue" . It should be the second way, I'll correct it.